# Accessing class method

Tags: php

I'm learning php and I am a little confuse. Should I use getInstance (like singleton) or I can create a new object (as in test2 method)

```
class myclass {
     private static $instance;

     public static function getInstance(){
        if(is_null(self::$instance)){
           self::$instance = new self();}
        return self::$instance;
     }

     public function printVar($var){
       echo 'Your var is : ' . $var . '<br/>';
     }

     public static function test1($var){
       $myclass = myclass::getInstance();

       for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
         $myclass->printVar($i);
       }
     }

     public static function test2($var){
       $myclass = new myclass();

       for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
         $myclass->printVar($i);
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like build singleton - you should use `getInstance`, otherwise you don't have do it. 
For more information you can refer to [design patterns](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP).